# If after interview HR replies back to "just check in" does that mean there is hope?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

Did an interview with a company that I really like to work there and and the day after the interview their HR that was arranging the interview replied back to me with a email like this:

> " just checking in .... team enjoyed meeting with you ... I should
>   have some very exciting news for you shortly! :) "

So does that mean the team that interviewed me is actually interested and have told her that yes we want this guy? or does that mean she just sent it on her own and sends the same to every candidate that does that interview? or what else?

I am just so nervous, waiting to see if I can work there or not.

Comment: There is a very high chance you'll get an offer. Usually we use such wording if we need to wait for approval by the work council or need some other kind of approval that is almost always granted.

Comment: @Roland thanks, made my day a little more hopeful.

Comment: FYI--It's called "keeping you warm", because they will want to talk with you again (for whatever reason), and they don't want you to run away. They might be keeping other people warm too.

Comment: It means there isn't no hope.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is usually the kind of language used when they're either already preparing an offer for you or you're on a very short shortlist (like 2 or 3 people left).

Its not a guarantee you'll get an offer, but that is very promising. Companies usually do this to reassure the candidate that an offer is soon forthcoming, but its currently still stuck in bureaucratic limbo (Approval stamps missing, worker council approval pending, union approval pending, stuff like that)

Comment: I think the last sentence means there is no shortlist.  It is still possible for final approval to fall through, but I would say there is a better than 80% chance they are going to make an offer.

Answer (score 2):

Despite some politicians that think the sky is falling, many fields, particularly technology fields, are in very high demand.  They don't want you wondering off and taking another position because they let the lines of communication go cold.  This seems like a good sign to me.

More than once I have either lost a candidate to a faster responding company, or taken the faster offer myself.  The tone here makes it seem they are indeed interested in moving you to the next step, whatever that is for this company.

Comment: thanks, from the recruiter agency I had heard it is very quick process . One interview and done ! Which I did that interview on Monday and got that email from HR on Tuesday

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark good luck, job hunts are always stressful IMO.